# How to implement variable parameter ICase in Postgres 9.1+

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Code below is used to implement ICase() (Switch in VB) function in Postgres 9.1 and above.

It has few limitations:

1. Number of parameters is fixed to 3. Actually icase can have number of parameters from 4 to 2*n+1
2. `resi` argument has fixed type `text`. ICase should accept also numberic, decimal, date or other data types for `resi` and return value should be same type as resi

How to fix this ?
Or is it better to create separate overload for every possible number of arguments and rosi type ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ICase(cond1 bool, res1 text, cond2 bool, res2 text,cond3 bool, res3 text, conddefault text )
  RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
SELECT CASE when $1 then $2 
            when $3 then $4
            when $5 then $6
else $7 end;
$BODY$ language sql immutable;
```

**Update**

I tried according to answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.icase(
    cond1 boolean,
    res1 anyelement,
    conddefault anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
' SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN $2 ELSE $3 END; '
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Statement

```
select icase( true, 1.0, 0 )
```

causes error

```
ERROR:  function icase(boolean, numeric, integer) does not exist
LINE 9: select icase( true, 1.0, 0 )
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How to fix this in 9.1+ so that second and third arguments can be int and numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see EDIT below for new approach.

If it's OK to provide your input as arrays, you could use this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.ICase(
  p_cond boolean[],
  p_array anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  v_arrlen integer;
BEGIN
  v_arrlen := array_upper(p_array, 1);
  IF v_arrlen <> array_upper(p_cond, 1) + 1 THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  FOR i IN 1..v_arrlen LOOP
    IF p_cond[i] THEN
      RETURN p_array[i];
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN p_array[v_arrlen];
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Try calling with:

```
SELECT * FROM ICase(ARRAY[FALSE, FALSE, TRUE], ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4])
```

which yields the result `3`

EDIT: Well since you're really trying to keep your original calls intact, I think it might just be easiest if you create all possible permutations of this function with dynamic queries.  It's ugly, but it works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_icase(p_num integer, p_types text[]) RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
  v_qry text;
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..p_num LOOP
  FOR j IN 1..array_upper(p_types, 1) LOOP
    v_qry := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION icase(';
    FOR k IN 1..i LOOP
        IF k > 1 THEN v_qry := v_qry || ', '; END IF;
        v_qry := v_qry || 'cond' || k || ' boolean, res' || k || ' ' || p_types[j];
    END LOOP;
    v_qry := v_qry || ', conddefault ' || p_types[j] || ') RETURNS ' || p_types[j] || ' AS $FUNC$ SELECT CASE ';
    FOR k in 1..(i * 2) BY 2 LOOP
        v_qry := v_qry || 'WHEN $' || k || ' THEN $' || k + 1 || ' ';
    END LOOP;
    v_qry := v_qry || 'ELSE $' || (i * 2) + 1 || ' END; $FUNC$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;';
    EXECUTE v_qry;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Then to build your bulk functions for max-conditionals/results of 10 and for result data types of either 'date', 'numeric', or 'text, run:

```
SELECT build_icase(10, ARRAY['date', 'numeric', 'text'])
```

This will build 30 functions for all iterations of how many conditional args you need to pass and all possible data types for your results.  After making this, I realized I could probably have abstracted this with `anyelement` which would cut this down to 10 functions (see EDIT2 below).  I don't have a lot of experience with `anyelement`, so I'm not sure if it runs into more casting errors than if you were to use explicit data types like in this example.

Be careful when running this, as it could create a lot of functions for you to potentially clean-up.  I recommend testing with low numbers and you can always replace `EXECUTE v_qry;` with `RAISE INFO 'v_qry is: %', v_qry;` which will just print out the dynamic queries as a message without executing them.

EDIT2: Below is a version that creates less functions by employing `anyelement`.  I didn't test this one, but looks good from here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_icase(p_num integer) RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
  v_qry text;
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..p_num LOOP
    v_qry := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION icase(';
    FOR k IN 1..i LOOP
        IF k > 1 THEN v_qry := v_qry || ', '; END IF;
        v_qry := v_qry || 'cond' || k || ' boolean, res' || k || ' anyelement';
    END LOOP;
    v_qry := v_qry || ', conddefault anyelement) RETURNS anyelement AS $FUNC$ SELECT CASE ';
    FOR k in 1..(i * 2) BY 2 LOOP
        v_qry := v_qry || 'WHEN $' || k || ' THEN $' || k + 1 || ' ';
    END LOOP;
    v_qry := v_qry || 'ELSE $' || (i * 2) + 1 || ' END; $FUNC$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;';
    EXECUTE v_qry;
END LOOP;
END; 
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: using arrays requres changung application. Can it done keeping method calling signature as in question, only adding or removin additional boolen and result columns?

Comment: It could be done with some very hacky dynamic queries, but I would need to know the exact signature of your call to tell if it would be feasible.  i.e. how do you pass in your booleans, and which specific data types do you expect to use as res values.  Can you provide a signature of all your possible calls (not including all possible number of args... just how each arg looks).  Keep in mind this is very much not a native feature since Postgres only supports variable args via default values, but that doesn't help here since we don't know when the `conddefault` value will appear, ahead of time.

Comment: Perhaps most importantly, is it ever possible that your `conddefault` value will ever be a boolean?

Comment: Signature can be `CREATE FUNCTION icase (VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS anyelement`. conddefault is the same type as resi. Theoretically resi and conddefault can be bool also, but for my needs it is sufficient if they all are can be either text, numeric or date types. Maybe it is possible to use select or for to enumerate over parameters and return first true result

Comment: I meant the signature of your calls.  e.g. how do your boolean cond values always look?  Would you ever use icase(0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4) or do you always use TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: Problem with using anyarray as your only arg is that it will always try to resolve all elements as boolean as long as you're passing your cond values into it.  Would you be able to pass all args into it as text (by casting with ::text)?

Comment: condition parameters in icase are always boolean. Expressions are generated from automatic expression converter, adding ::text casts makes this too sophisticated. I will create as much icase() signatures as required, thank you.

Comment: I tried this but encountered issue. I updated question.

Comment: I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330555/how-to-use-mixed-int-and-numeric-aruments-in-icase-in-postgres-9-1

Answer (score 1):

Creating a PostgreSQL function with identical argument behavior to that of `ICase()` from VB is currently not possible as of PostgreSQL 9.4.

The two current limitations are:

1. [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) may only be specified once at the end of a function (so `2*n+1` is not natively enforceable).
2. While [polymorphic arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html#AEN55205) are supported, only one data type may be specified per call since it converts the `VARIADIC` argument to an `ARRAY` (so `ARRAY[TRUE, 'text']` is invalid).

However, if we rearrange the arguments, very similar behavior can be achieved by using array and [pseudo-type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-pseudo.html) arguments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ICase(boolean[], anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
SELECT
  $2[i]
FROM
  generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i)
WHERE
  $1[i] IS TRUE
UNION ALL
SELECT
  $3
LIMIT 1;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

1. The first argument accepts an array of conditional `boolean` values.
2. The second argument accepts an array of values of any data type.
3. The third argument accepts any data type, but it must match the data type of the elements of the second argument array.

The first `TRUE` element of the `boolean[]` of `$1` will result in the same index from `$2` to be returned:

```
SELECT ICase(ARRAY[0=1,1=1], ARRAY['a','b'], 'default');
 icase 
-------
 b
(1 row)
```

If there are no `TRUE` elements within `$1`, then `$3` will be returned:

```
SELECT ICase(ARRAY[FALSE,FALSE], ARRAY['a','b'], 'default');
  icase  
---------
 default
(1 row)
```

Any data type is supported for `$2` and `$3`:

```
SELECT ICase(ARRAY[TRUE], ARRAY['12:00'::time], NOW()::time);
  icase   
----------
 12:00:00
(1 row)

SELECT ICase(ARRAY[FALSE], ARRAY[1], -1);
 icase 
-------
    -1
(1 row)
```

You could theoretically create a composite type consisting of a `boolean` and another data type and create a function like `ICaseText(text, VARIADIC boolean_text[])`, but it would not be as flexible as the example above.

I'm not sure about VB's `ICase()`, but using a function like this does not allow you to make use of short-circuiting a subexpression like the builtin [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) does, for example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 1/0 END;
 case 
------
    1
(1 row)
```

The `1/0` is never actually evaluated, so we don't get a "division by zero" error.

The same does not hold true when using the `ICase` function:

```
SELECT ICase(ARRAY[TRUE], ARRAY[1], 1/0);
ERROR:  division by zero
```

Comment: Thank you. Parameter order cannot changed. Maybe it is possible to treat all parameters  as polymorphic `CREATE FUNCTION icase (VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS anyelement`, use for loop to enumerate over them and return next parameter after first true parameter ?

Comment: I mentioned the limitation there in my answer. `VARIADIC anyarray` only allows one data type at the same time. So `ICase(TRUE, 'text')` will end up being `$1 = ARRAY[TRUE, 'text']` inside the function, which is an invalid array and will currently fail.