# How to use mixed int and numeric arguments in a Postgres 9.1+ function

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, iif

I'm looking for a way to create an `icase()` function which works with any second and third parameter compatible data types.
I tried in Postgres 9.4:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.icase(
    cond1 boolean,
    res1 anyelement,
    conddefault anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement AS
' SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN $2 ELSE $3 END; '
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

But:

```
select icase( true, 1.0, 0 )
```

causes error:

> ```
> ERROR:  function icase(boolean, numeric, integer) does not exist
> LINE 9: select icase( true, 1.0, 0 )
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

How to fix this in 9.1+ so that second and third arguments can be either int or numeric?

This method may be called if both second and third parameters are `text`, `char(n)`, `date`, `numeric` or `int` types.

Comment: Problem is `anyelement` only resolves to one data type per function, not per use.  Even if you avoided `anyelement` and went with hard coded data types, you cannot write a function that returns either a numeric or integer value.  You must choose one per function.  I imagine if you changed your function call to `select icase(true, 1.0, 0.0)`, it would work as intended.

Comment: In other words, I would take this as a hint to start looking into ways to pre-process your input to get these things into the format necessary to work with postgres.

Comment: Wait, are 2nd and 3rd parameter supposed to be the ***same*** in any case: both `int` or both `numeric` or both date etc.? Your title and example hint in a different direction than your final statement ... Also, do you need the result to have the exact same data type or would a `text` representation do the job?

Comment: second and third parameters can be: `(int,numeric), (numeric,int), (int,int), (numeric,numeric), (date,date), (char(n) , char(n)), (text, char(n)), (char(n), text), (text,text)` For mixed numeric/int parameters result can be always numeric. For non mixed parameters result should be same as parameter type. For numeric and date parameters text result cannot probably returned since this is used in expression and prostgres will probably produe error if text is used in numeric expression, automatic casting is problably not supported anymore in 9.1+

Comment: @Shawn this is called from automatic converter which converts VFP expression to postgres. Same expressions are usedby two different languages. So expressions are already defined and their changing  should avoided is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polymorphic types are strict in this moment - in other cases, PostgreSQL try to cast constants to most common type, but this step is missing for polymorphic types - so in this case, when you have described issue, you have to cast explicitly or you should not to use polymorphic types. Plan B is over *function overloading*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.icase1(cond1 boolean,
                                         res1 integer, conddefault integer)
RETURNS integer AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN $2 ELSE $3 END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.icase1(cond1 boolean,
                                         res1 numeric, conddefault numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN $2 ELSE $3 END;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then your code will work as expected:

```
postgres=> select icase1(true, 1.0, 0);
 icase1 
--------
    1.0
(1 row)

postgres=> select icase1(true, 1.0, 1.0);
 icase1 
--------
    1.0
(1 row)

postgres=> select icase1(true, 1, 0);
 icase1 
--------
      1
(1 row)
```